# Best practice: Deploying a standalone application on linux/raspberry pi

Tags: .net, linux, deployment, raspberry-pi, production-environment

I have a mono/dotnet-based application which interacts with several interfaces of the raspberry pi it's running on. Now I want to make it production ready.

However, I am not sure where to place this application.

I've seen multiple examples such as

- /opt/appname
- /var/appname (usually just for web application in sub-dir www)
- /home/appname

Is it okay to place a production application in the home directory and what is the best practice for where to place a production application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard is a great place to learn more about the intent behind the filesystem layout in linux.  For your usage I would recommend either `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thank you very much - just what I needed